# Using linregress to calculate slope and intercept

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file with two columns (x,y) of data. I want to calculate the slope and intercept of the values in this file using linregress, as I think this would be easiest.

This list, which is read in, looks like this

```
95  68
94  67.99028594
93  67.98057049
92  67.97085365
91  67.96113542
90  67.9514158
89  67.94169479
88  67.93197239
87  67.9222486
86  67.91252341
85  67.90279683
84  67.89306886
83  67.8833395
82  67.87360874
81  67.86387658
80  67.85414303
79  67.84440809
78  67.83467174
77  67.824934
76  67.81519486
75  67.80545432
74  67.79571238
73  67.78596905
72  67.77622431
71  67.76647817
70  67.75673062
69  67.74698168
68  67.73723133
67  67.72747958
66  67.71772642
65  67.70797186
64  67.6982159
63  67.68845852
62  67.67869974
61  67.66893956
60  67.65917796
59  67.64941496
58  67.63965055
57  67.62988473
56  67.62011749
55  67.61034885
54  67.6005788
53  67.59080733
52  67.58103445
51  67.57126015
50  67.56148445
49  67.55170732
48  67.54192879
47  67.53214883
46  67.52236746
45  67.51258468
44  67.50280047
43  67.49301485
42  67.4832278
41  67.47343934
40  67.46364946
39  67.45385816
38  67.44406543
37  67.43427129
36  67.42447572
35  67.41467872
34  67.40488031
33  67.39508047
32  67.3852792
31  67.37547651
30  67.36567239
29  67.35586684
28  67.34605987
27  67.33625147
26  67.32644164
25  67.31663038
24  67.30681769
23  67.29700357
22  67.28718801
21  67.27737103
20  67.26755261
19  67.25773276
18  67.24791148
17  67.23808876
16  67.2282646
15  67.21843901
14  67.20861199
13  67.19878352
12  67.18895362
11  67.17912228
10  67.1692895
9   67.15945528
8   67.14961963
7   67.13978253
6   67.12994399
5   67.120104
```

I am new to python, and have written some trivial code that I had hoped would do this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import linregress

fileNameIN_pres = '/Somepathhere/prescription.txt'

with open(fileNameIN_pres) as f:
    for l in f:
        x, y = l.split()
        X1 = np.array(x)
        X2 = np.array(y)
        print X1,X2

    print linregress(X1,X2)
```

When I print X1 and X2, I get the columns I want, so the code does what I want up to that point. When I ask it to print linregress I get an error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_mstats_common.py", line 87, in linregress
    n = len(x)
TypeError: len() of unsized object
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

Any suggestions how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

though I don't know the file exactly, it would be like this:

```
X = []
Y = []
with open(fileNameIN_pres) as f:
    for l in f:
        x, y = l.split()
        X.append(x) 
        Y.append(y)

X = np.asarray(X);
Y = np.asarray(Y);
model = linregress(X, Y)
slope, intercept = model.slope, model.intercept
```

you can predict your Y from new_x by

```
predict = slope*new_x + intercept
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited the original to include the list format. I tried copying and pasting your answer, but I get a new error: "TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type". What does this mean?

Comment: i had to specify explicitly that both values were floats....

        X.append(float(x)) 
        Y.append(float(y))

seems to work when i print model

LinregressResult(slope=0.0097765420267558675, intercept=67.072169262838045, rvalue=0.99999855560881434, pvalue=2.678067576140719e-248, stderr=1.7613600886131683e-06)

Thanks again!